# how to run test in IE using maven pom

Tags: java, maven, internet-explorer, selenium

I am trying to run test exported from Selenium IDE in Java language in Internet Explorer using maven. But could not declare dependencies in pom.xml . My POM file:

```
<plugin>
...
<systemPropertyVariables>
        <webdriver.chrome.driver>${webdriver.chrome}</webdriver.chrome.driver>
        <webdriver.iexplorer.driver>${webdriver.iexplorer}</webdriver.iexplorer.driver>
</systemPropertyVariables>
</plugin>
...
<profile>
  <id>iexplorer</id>
  <properties>
    <env>local</env>
    <webdriver.iexplorer>C:\auto_tools\IEDriverServer.exe</webdriver.iexplorer>
    <user.username></user.username>
    <user.password></user.password>
    <grid2.hub></grid2.hub>
    <site.url>http://php4dvd.com.ua/</site.url>
    <browser.name>iexplorer</browser.name>
    <browser.version></browser.version>
    <browser.platform></browser.platform>
  </properties>
</profile>
```

I am trying run test in terminal with next command line:

> mvn test -P iexplorer

As answer I get message:

> Failed tests:
>     Login>TestBase.init:38 »  Unrecognized browser type: iexplorer

Running test in chrome works fine for me:

> mvn test -P chrome

In firefox, test running also... What I did wrong with Internet Explorer?

==============================================

```
File file = new File("C:/auto_tools/IEDriverServer.exe");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
    InternetExplorerDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
```

This decision works for me, but I need running test exactly with using pom.xml file.

Look forward for your help!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

pls try

```
<webdriver.iexplorer>C:/auto_tools/IEDriverServer.exe</webdriver.iexplorer>
```

replace above line below in your pom .xml file

```
<properties>
    <env>local</env>
    <webdriver.iexplorer>C:\auto_tools\IEDriverServer.exe</webdriver.iexplorer>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it does not help. Chrome driver declared in this way <webdriver.chrome>C:\auto_tools\chromedriver.exe</webdriver.chrome> and it works...With IE I have a problem

Comment: Thanks a lot. Let me try once doing the same setup.

Comment: Thank you! If you need full maven project, you can find it here:
https://github.com/Arkhypov/Selenium_tests/tree/master/SeleniumStart/training

Comment: Thank you for your attempts to help!, please let me know if you have questions or you found a decision.

Comment: Its a local run or Grid run you trying ? Error as per you is Failed tests: Login>TestBase.init:38 » Unrecognized browser type: iexplorer.  Your code says if (!(null == platform || "".equals(platform))) {. The browser.name set is Safari , will change to IE . 
   capabilities.setPlatform(Platform.valueOf(PropertyLoader.loadProperty("browser.platform")));
  }

Comment: Working on your code..... its nice work Good if you wrap EventFiringWebDriver on top of WebDriver which will return EventFiringDriver wguch sit top of WebDriver or RemoteWebDriver. Already you are reading the driver details from the Property file........ Just a suggestion no help to your current issue.

Comment: Hi  Asit Tripathy,

Thank you very much for your attempts to help. 
Due to http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-api/2.41.0/org/openqa/selenium/remote/BrowserType.java#BrowserType.0IE , yes <browser.name>iexplore</browser.name> is correct, but unfortunately it does not work also...I think this is bug of last versions of IEDriver or Maven for using pom.xml in terminal. 

Again, thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot Yevgen. Sorry cold not help much but i i get any crack will pass on to you.